# BASH command-line method to obtain OUI vendor info from MAC address

Tags: bash, macos, curl, grep, wifi

I' m trying to reproduce a method outlined in an old [UnixStackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248769/command-line-tool-to-obtain-oui-vendor-info-from-mac-address) to use a curl command to search for the vendor name using a MAC address obtained locally. The command is:

curl -sS "http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt" | grep -i "$OUI" | cut -d')' -f2 | tr -d 't'

However, it produces nothing when I run it. I've verified that "OUI" contains my MAC address to search on. Example:

echo $OUI

EC-58-EA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because HTTP server return a `301 Moved Permanently` response

```
➜  ~ curl http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt -i
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.12.0
Date: Sun, 07 Mar 2021 05:41:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Location: http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.txt
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Indicating new location ---> `< Location: http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.txt`

You can curl new location o tell to curl to follow 301 redirection : `curl -L http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt`

#### testing

```
➜  ~ curl -LsS "http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt" | grep -i "EC-58-EA" | cut -d')' -f2 | tr -d 't'
        Ruckus Wireless
```